# Cache Docker object files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A section of my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
RUN mkdir path/to/module/
COPY path/to/module /path/to/module
WORKDIR /path/to/module
RUN cmake .
RUN make
```

I have a lot of C files in this module so this takes a few minutes to run. If I were to change a single file in this module, the `COPY` layer will have to run again and everything after it will be discarded from cache. Then, `make` will remake every C file in the module. How can I cache my object files so that the `COPY` only copies over new/edited files and doesn't discard all of the object files?

Comment: Every Docker command (RUN, COPY...) creates a new layer, every layer is immutable. So basically, if a file has changed in `path/to/module` the layer created by the COPY command and everything after will be invalidated. This is by design.